# Custom Request Handlers/Components with Solr-4.x

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I was referring this http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html for making custom handlers in solr. They are pretty nice but conform to the old apis. Is there any similar example I can refer to for solr-4.3.0.

Comment: I do not think the RequestHandler has been so modified that this example would not work.

Comment: What should be a sample return type of buildCustomQuery1() method and also there is no such method SolrPluginUtils.setReturnFields(req, rsp);

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to download the Solr [source](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler) and check the existing implementations Of RequestHandlers. There are some that are quiet simplistic and can give you a good grasp of the API and a starting point.`PingRequestHandler` comes first to mind, if your goal is to do something very simple. For more complex scenarios look for the ones that make use of components and take a look in solr config for their initialization parameters.

Best of luck!